# "Wallpaper" cipher puzzle

Tags: cipher, steganography

One day, I opened my phone and noticed my wallpaper has changed.

I also noticed there was a note in front of my phone.

I read the note, saying:

> Your phone has been hacked.
>
> I changed the lock.
>
> You must do a specific task.
>
> The clue is hidden in the wallpaper.

What do I do?

[image: slime]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looking at the RGB channels, I noticed that

> the green and blue seemed random, but the red channels seemed to have a pattern.

If you

> overlay a red filter onto the image

you get this:

> [image]

This *clearly* has a message in it: by replacing the pixels that are "extreme" colors (either all black or all red) we get this image:

> [image]

and finally, shrinking it down gives us the intended message:

> [image]
>  CLICK TOP RIGHT TEN TIMES AND PRESS HOME.

(Or you can just check the metadata, as nathoenk did while I was making this...)

Comment: Upvoted for your last line! :-)

Comment: Hmmm.  I just stared at the image until I convinced myself that I saw a cat in a pirate hat....

Answer (score 16):

The answer is

> CLICK TOP RIGHT TEN TIMES AND PRESS HOME

explanation

> Since I don't have photoshop, I open file via online inspector and found that sentences at Text Layer Name and Text Layer Text. So I conclude that answer hidden at layer name. This screenshot from online inspector.
>  [image]